# How to use operator $substrBytes in mongodb go sdk?

Tags: mongodb, go, substring, mongo-go-driver

*Here is my question:*

There are many documents in my MongoDB who have a field named `create_time`, and that field is a string that looks like `2022-08-19T11:22:33`. Now I would like to filter out documents created at a certain date. That logic can be easily achieved by SQL query( if they can be stored in a MySQL table with a `create_time` field ):
`select * from my_table where left(create_time, 10)='2022-08-19';`. But how to achieve that in mongo go sdk?

*Here is what I've found:*

1. There is an operator that can return a substring of a string: [$substrBytes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/#mongodb-expression-exp.-substrBytes), and its CLI syntax has the form `{ $substrBytes: [ <string expression>, <byte index>, <byte count> ] }`
2. I browsed through the [examples offered by mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go) and found that filter seems to be a nested `bson.D`.

But since the key of `bson.D` is of string type, I cannot do something like `bson.D{bson.M{"$substrBytes": bson.A{"base_info.upload_time", 0, 10}}:"2022-08-19"}`. So how can I achieve my goal? I didn't find any related examples in official documentation.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use aggregation, convert string to date using aggregate operator and apply a match on that newly created field.